# Writing a spec for an observer that triggers a mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, observer-pattern, actionmailer

I'm writing a simple comment observer which triggers a mailer whenever a new comment is created. All the relevant code is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/c3234352b3c4776ce132

Note that the specs for `Notification` pass, but the specs for `CommentObserver` fail because `Notification.new_comment` is returning `nil`. I found that I could get a passing spec by using this instead:

```
describe CommentObserver do
  it "sends a notification mail after a new comment is created" do
    Factory(:comment)
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.should_not be_empty
  end
end
```

This is not ideal, however, because it tests the behavior of the mailer in the observer's spec, when all I really want to know is that it's triggering the mailer correctly. Why is the mailer returning `nil` in the original version of the spec? What is the best approach for speccing this type of functionality? I'm using Rails 3 and RSpec 2 (and Factory Girl, if that matters).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*for context*:

```
class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(comment)
    Notification.new_comment(comment).deliver
  end
end

# spec
require 'spec_helper'

describe CommentObserver do
  it "sends a notification mail after a new comment is created" do
    @comment = Factory.build(:comment)
    Notification.should_receive(:new_comment).with(@comment)
    @comment.save
  end
end
```

In this case you want to check that `deliver` is called on the Notification, so that's where the expectation should go. The rest of the spec code is there to set up the expectation and trigger it. Try it this way:

```
describe CommentObserver do
  it "sends a notification mail after a new comment is created" do
    @comment = Factory.build(:comment)
    notification = mock(Notification)
    notification.should_receive(:deliver)
    Notification.stub(:new_comment).with(@comment).and_return(notification)
    @comment.save
  end
end
```

> Why is the mailer returning nil in the
>   original version of the spec?

I believe this is because message expectations act like stubs -- if no value is specified in `.and_return()` or by passing in a block, `should_receive` returns `nil`.

Comment: I get now why the mailer was returning nil - I didn't realize should_receive implicitly turns its receiver into a stub. I disagree that what I want to be testing here is the delivery of the message, however. That is already covered in the spec for the Notification class. All I want to confirm here is that the new_comment method of Notification is called, and the example you show seems tightly coupled to the implementation of Notification.new_comment.

Comment: Well to be fair this doesn't test the actual delivery, it only specifies that `deliver` is called. And after all the example is named "sends a notification mail", not "creates a Notification instance" :)

But if you wanted to avoid checking `deliver`, you could set the expectation on 'new_comment`, and change the mock to `mock(Notification).as_null_object`, so that it ignores the `deliver` message.